# javascript event update

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, livequery

My ui-autocomplete should send ajax request to different path's. 
My script changes this path on change select event. But event do not updates and sends request to old url.

I tried live(), on(), livequery(). nothing works.

How to update event?

My input autocomplete field:

```
<input class="specialization_names ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete-source="/specializations">
```

I'm changing `data-autocomplete-source`

Event I'm binging next way(generated by coffeescript)

```
_ref = $('.specialization_names');
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  input = _ref[_i];
  $(input).on('focus', function() {
    return $(input).catcomplete({
      source: $(input).data('autocomplete-source')
    });
  });
}
```

or change `on()` to `live()` or to plugin livequery

This code changing url on select.

```
var select, _i, _len, _ref;

_ref = $('.resume_scopes');
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  select = _ref[_i];
  $(select).on('change', function() {
    var scope_id;
    scope_id = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('value');
    return $(this).siblings('.specialization_names').attr("data-autocomplete-source", "/specializations/" + scope_id);
  });
}
```

Is there any way to manually refresh one time an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.data` only reads from the `data-*` attribute once (the 1st time you call `.data` on the element to get the value).  `.attr` updates the attribute on the element, but jQuery's `.data` has cached the value.  It you want to update it, try using `.data` instead.

```
return $(this).siblings('.specialization_names').data("autocomplete-source", "/specializations/" + scope_id);
```

Comment: Just 5 minutes ago understood that too. Thanks for solution.